# response of multipart request is returning <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: android, api, http-post, multipart

i am trying to send an http post request to server as a multipart request but the response of the api is always returning as . i have done the following code but was not able to find out what is wrong with it.

```
String saveGroupUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.base_url)+ getResources().getString(R.string.save_group);
                Log.v("save group url==>", saveGroupUrl);
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(saveGroupUrl);

                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try {



                    entity.addPart("device_id",new StringBody(My_Application.androidId));
                    entity.addPart("token_no",new StringBody(prefs.gettokendata()));
                    entity.addPart("user_id",new StringBody(prefs.getuserid()));

                    entity.addPart("group_name", new StringBody(strGrpName));
                    Log.v("group name==>", strGrpName);

                    entity.addPart("short_desc", new StringBody(strDesc));
                    Log.v("group desc==>", strDesc);

                    entity.addPart("description", new StringBody(strLongDesc));
                    Log.v("group long desc==>", strLongDesc);



                    httppost.setEntity(entity);

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity(); 
                     if (resEntity != null) {    
                           Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                     }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: It seems like a server issue to me. Are you sure the web service is correctly configured to return the values you are expecting?

Comment: yes the web service is correctly configured. because it is working fine on I-PHONE

Comment: From what I can see (I'm not really familiar with MultiPartEntity admittedly), there's nothing wrong with the code. Either you are accessing a wrong URL or there's something wrong with the web service. Check the URL and see if you are accessing the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing a wrong URL. Everything works fine. However,

First of all when you visit the site make sure you get the cookies that exist in the response for the first time before making the request, and then when you have to make the request, just put inside that request the cookies that you got.

By the way, I suggest you use `JSOUP` or `Apache HTTP Client` instead of the native API. Trust me that you'll save time and lines of codes.